# Prevent voltage drops on Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, dip

I got a 4D systems Serial uLCD and been messing with- pretty awesome kit. But when i got round  to reading files of a FAT16 partition, wave, graphics nothing was happening. I was getting ACK/NACK randomly and just did not make sence.

[I got to this article on the forum.](http://4d.websitetoolbox.com/post?Problems-playing-wave-files-5430684)

How can i prevent this voltage "dip" from happening on the 5v. i suspect it happens because it has to power up the SD card and gets corrupt bits from the start.. but that is not my issue. This guy said if he uses batteries it works for him (and its only Arduino Mega with this problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regulator cannot supply enough current then you will get intermittent problems. The voltage will sag when something attempts to draw more current than is available.
The solution in the link sounds reasonable - have you tried this? If not I would try it and if things still don't work then update things here.
The other thing you could try is to add a reservoir capacitor (say >10uF, preferably low ESR, or parallel a few to achieve this) across power and ground near the SD card (or whatever you think is causing the issue) 
This will only work if the average total current is less than the regulator can supply, which sounds possible. It will deal with any short demands for large currents, rather than the regulator.

Comment: Yea i put a 9V battery onto my Arduino (it says it can regualte from 7v to 12 safely)  - And nothing- my code is like his and i still cant get my gfx or wave to work. i suspect it might be the 4gb sd card is not supported- ebcasue i cant even write to it using the SGC call.  Thanks for you answer makes sence. cant give it more from nothing :)

Comment: That won't make any difference - you need to put some power in *after* the regulator, or direct into the display as it says in the link. You can't use the 9V battery, so use e.g. 3 x AA (alkaline, should be ~4.5V) or 4xNimH (should be ~4.8V)

Comment: I would put the power direct to the display (so + of battery pack to display Vdd, - to ground) This way you use the regulator power too. Putting the battery power in after the regulator might damage the regulator, depending on what type it is.

Comment: Ahhhh - really?.. i thought the regulator was running out of juice to give out-- OK... im gonna power the unit up on its own then.

Comment: OKAY! The screen is almost 40% brighter now. But still no sound. damn annoying

Comment: What exactly did you do? Be careful here as I think we may be getting some wires crossed :-) If you have a schematic it would be easier to be more precise with advice and prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: Yea it seems like the SD card is causing me grief. when its in none of my other basic text stuff work- remove and reset.. tadaaa.. hmm :( Thanks for help anyway! very usefull- i wont make the mistake to run it off arduino 5v on the final product.

Comment: Dont worry- I use a wall 5v adapter and put it to the Vcc of the  uLCD. It supports 4.0v to 5.5v.